# SQL server 2008 DB mail sending Fail Issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sp-send-dbmail, dbmail

I have Created Profile and Account in My server. While sending a test mail it Throws an error:

> The mail could not be sent to the recipients because of the mail
>   server failure. (Sending Mail using Account 3 (2013-05-30T19:07:28).
>   Exception Message: Cannot send mails to mail server. (Transaction
>   failed. The server response was: Mail from *username@yourdomail.com*
>   rejected for policy reasons.). )

While in another server, same profile and same account with same SMTP server, working fine.

Comment: I've seen this before. You need to check the sender and SMTP server logs for more information. It's likely just a configuration issue.

Comment: Thanks Preet, I have check all the logs. I think its an SMTP povider Issues. Could't still Solved. Tried so many time creating Profile and account again and again.. Not Solved..